# How do I change an ActiveIndex numeric value to text?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, indexing

In my ASP.Net web page, I want to change the active index numerical values to text values.

For instance, the active index currently renders numerically as 1, 2, 3, 4, etc...  I would like to have this index render as a, b, c, d, etc...

Could you please suggest a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert them easily using:

```
char c = (char)(96 + index);
```

It will return a when index is 1, b when 2 and so on...

You will have to write additional code if you want aa for index value of 27.

Answer (score 1):

write simple mapping function which returns corresponding alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289792/int-to-char-in-c) will help.  Basically you can just cast your int to a char if you want a really rudimentary solution.