# C#. How come when I use TextReader.Read() it returns an int value? Possible to convert to char?

Tags: c#, input, char, int32, textreader

So TextReader.ReadLine() returns a string, but TextReader.Read() returns an int value. This int value also seems to be in some sort of format that I don't recognize. Is it possible to convert this integer to a character? Thanks for any help.

EDIT:

TextReader Values = new StreamReader(@"txt");

```
    string SValue1;
    int Value1;       
    Value1 = Values.Read();        
    Console.WriteLine(Value1);
    Console.ReadKey();
```

When it reads out the value it gives me 51 as the output. The first character in the txt file is 3. Why does it do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Int to Char in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289792/int-to-char-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation for the StringReader class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.aspx) (a sub-class of TextReader), the return value of `Read()` can be converted to a char, but you need to check if you're at the end of file/string first (by checking for -1).  For example, in this modified code from the documentation:

```
while (true)
{
    int integer = stringReader.Read();

    // Check for the end of the string before converting to a character.
    if (integer == -1)
        break;

    char character = (char) integer; // CONVERT TO CHAR HERE

    // do stuff with character...
}
```

Comment: Thank for the help =] why does the read value initially exist as just a number?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation tells you: it returns -1 if there is no more data to read, and otherwise it returns the character, as an integer. The integer is not "in some sort of format"; integers are raw data. It is, rather, characters that are "formatted"; bytes on the disk must be interpreted as characters.

After checking for -1 (which is not a valid character value and represents the end of stream - that's why the method works this way: so you can check), you can convert by simply casting.

Answer (score 2):

`Read` returns an `int` o that end-of-stream (-1) can be detected.  Yes, you just cast the result to a char as in `var c = (int) reader.Read();`.

Typical usage:

```
while (true)
{
    int x = reader.Read();
    if (x == -1) break;
    char c = (char) x;
    // Handle the character
}
```