# How to replace char(10) [sql server] to something else in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, replace, newline

Simple Question, the string im saving into my database uses char(10) to represent new line, i want to replace it with `<br />` before saving it into the database so its displayed as an actual new line when i view it in a html page.

how im supposed to do that ? since there is no char(10) in c#

im using:

```
StringName.Replace("char(10)", "<br />");
```

which doesnt work.

my Code :

```
 var InscriptionText = Request["InscriptionText"];
InscriptionText.Replace("\n", "<br />");
var qry = "Instert into .." (normal query)
db.query(qry);
```

then i view the data in the databse to find that it didnt replace it and its saved as "line1line2line3line4"

Comment: Do you mean `char(10) = '\n'`? Why not `StringName = StringName.Replace("\n", "<br />");`.

Comment: How can you say `doesnt work`? Show the code how you're using it.

Comment: When i use "\n" in an update query it doesn work but char(10) works fine, ive tried \n in c# too, didnt work.

Comment: Please share the code which doesn't work, how can we assume what you're writing?

Comment: `Replace` method returns a new string, you need to catch it as well. Just change the second line to `InscriptionText = InscriptionText.Replace("\n", "<br />");`

Comment: char(10) in C# should be `(char)10`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/289792/5089204

Comment: Give us the real cleartext and what output you're expecting. Do you have a literal "char(10)" in that text?  And ofcouse you can have a `char` representing the number `10`, it's `'\n'` (or `char c = (char)10`).

Comment: @Shaharyar Ops sorry its my first time using this method, Post it as answer to accept it.

Comment: How do you *view the data in the database* ? SSMS will not show line breaks in grid-data. Switch the output to text-output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Replace` method returns a new string, you need to save it.

Just change the second line:

```
var InscriptionText = Request["InscriptionText"];
InscriptionText = InscriptionText.Replace("\n", "<br />");
//...
```

But, I would suggest you not to edit the actual user input. Save it as it comes to you. And replace it while showing it back to user. Just a suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

In c# you could do this:

```
string breakText1 = "Some text without a line break.";
string breakText2 = "Some text " + Environment.NewLine + "with a line break.";
string breakText3 = "Some text \nwith a new line.";
string breakText4 = "Some text \rwith a carriage return.";

Console.WriteLine("Strings before replace...");
Console.WriteLine(breakText1);
Console.WriteLine(breakText2);
Console.WriteLine(breakText3);
Console.WriteLine(breakText4);

Console.WriteLine("Strings after replace...");
Console.WriteLine(breakText1.Replace("\r\n", "<br />").Replace("\r", "<br />").Replace("\n", "<br />").Replace("<br /><br />", "<br />"));
Console.WriteLine(breakText2.Replace("\r\n", "<br />").Replace("\r", "<br />").Replace("\n", "<br />").Replace("<br /><br />", "<br />"));
Console.WriteLine(breakText3.Replace("\r\n", "<br />").Replace("\r", "<br />").Replace("\n", "<br />").Replace("<br /><br />", "<br />"));
Console.WriteLine(breakText4.Replace("\r\n", "<br />").Replace("\r", "<br />").Replace("\n", "<br />").Replace("<br /><br />", "<br />"));
```

Of course, this could be done much more elegantly, but this gets the idea across and covers the different common combinations of Carriage Return and/or Line Feed.