# JS decryption method translate to C#

Tags: c#, .net

I need some help with JS code translation to C#.
JS Code:

```
function Decription(string) {
            var newString = '',
                char, codeStr, firstCharCode, lastCharCode;
            var ft = escape(string);
            string = decodeURIComponent(ft);
            for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
                char = string.charCodeAt(i);
                if (char > 132) {
                    codeStr = char.toString(10);
                    firstCharCode = parseInt(codeStr.substring(0, codeStr.length - 2), 10);
                    lastCharCode = parseInt(codeStr.substring(codeStr.length - 2, codeStr.length), 10) + 31;
                    newString += String.fromCharCode(firstCharCode) + String.fromCharCode(lastCharCode);
                } else {
                    newString += string.charAt(i);
                }
            }
            return newString;
        }
```

And I tied to translate on C#:

```
private string Decription(string encriptedText)
        {
            string ft = Regex.Escape(encriptedText);
            string text = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(ft);
            string newString = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
            {
                var ch = (int)text[i];
                if(ch > 132)
                {
                    var codeStr = Convert.ToString(ch, 10);
                    var firstCharCode = Convert.ToInt32(codeStr.Substring(0, codeStr.Length - 2), 10);
                    var lastCharCode = Convert.ToInt32(codeStr.Substring(codeStr.Length - 2, codeStr.Length), 10) + 31;
                }
            }

        }
```

But how I can translate this row:

```
newString += String.fromCharCode(firstCharCode) + String.fromCharCode(lastCharCode);
```

Maybe do you know equivalent method to String.fromCharCode() on C# ?

Comment: You can do `newString += (char) firstChartCode; newString += (char) lastCharCode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
public static void Main()
{
    // from 97 to a
    int i = 97;
    Console.WriteLine(StringFromCharCode(97));
}

public static string StringFromCharCode(int code) => ((char)code).ToString();
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zX9Aq0)

Note that you may want to use a `StringBuilder` instead of concatening `string` in your case.

Related to [Int to Char in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289792/int-to-char-in-c-sharp) (Read it. It includes a nice comment about cast vs `Convert.ToChar`)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `Convert.ToChar` method, `Convert.ToChar(97)` will return `a`.