# How can I convert Int data type to Char data type in C#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert an integer value which is '36' to its corresponding character value which is '$' in accordance with ASCII & Unicode Character Codes.

How can I do that type of conversion?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Int to Char in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289792/int-to-char-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Just a cast: `char c = (char) i;`

Comment: I am working on windows forms doesn't it matter ?